# How do i make the user input a number, and if the user inputs a letter it returns an error - VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to make sure the user inputs a number between 1 and 9, which is easy, but i also want to make sure that if the user inputs say "hello", it will return an error and let the user try again, either infinetely or to a certain amount of times

I've been using Try Catch with a while statement to make sure the user does actually enter a number, where it does work, but returns an error.

```
 Ans = Console.ReadLine
        While Ans < 1 Or Ans > 9
            Try
                Console.WriteLine("Error, enter a number between 1 and 9")
                Ans = Console.ReadLine
            Catch
                Console.WriteLine("That is not a number between 1 and 9")
            End Try
        End While
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Int32.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse) method allows you to have a better control on the user inputs without requiring a costly exception handler. Simply, if the input is not a number the method returns false. The code is slightly more complex because you choose to not accept numbers bigger than 9

```
Dim num as Integer
Do 
   Console.WriteLine("Enter a number between 1 and 9")
   Dim Ans as String = Console.ReadLine
   if Not Int32.TryParse(Ans, num) OrElse num > 9 Then
        Console.WriteLine("That is not a number between 1 and 9")
   End If
While num < 1 OrElse num > 9
Console.WriteLine($"Entered Number is {num}")
```

Comment: i saw that there's a variable called "isNumeric". I tried it and it doesnt work
is there a reason for that?

Comment: Also, why did you add the $ and curly brackets?

Comment: IsNumeric comes from the old VB6 days and it is not very type aware. You could pass a button or anything and it will not complain. Moreover the IsNumeric tells you just that (number or not) but it doesn't convert the string to a specific number type. IsNumeric accepts 1.2 as a number but if you want an integer then its response is wrong. I suggest you to learn as soon as possible how to use [Option Strict On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement)

Comment: Here the docs about [Interpolated strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/strings/interpolated-strings)

Answer (score 0):

Steve is right, but just to show you how IsNumeric is used and how to give different errors with it:

```
If IsNumeric(ans) Then
    If ans > 1 AndAlso ans < 9 Then
        'it's a number and it's between 1 and 9
    Else
        'it's a number but NOT between 1 and 9
    End If
Else
    'not a number
End If
```